# extract data from PDF File to Excel or CSV

Tags: pdf, extract

I'm trying to extract data from PDF file using Power Bi, but some values are not able to be extracted it gives me "null, image" values[image]

is there any other way to extract the data from this PDF File to excel

Thanks